# Make Ansible trust my custom CA on macOS and CentOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ansible, urllib

I am setting up a web service that is reachable over HTTPS and it uses an internal CA. I want Ansible to verify the certificate so I need to make it trust this CA. I am running Ansible on both macOS and CentOS, so I need to make it trust my custom CA on both these types of operating systems.

I have tried to put my CA certificate inside `/etc/ssl/certs/` and added it as to `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem` using `blockinfile` but none of those have worked. I would prefer a way that is easy to clean up, like adding the CA file to a directory instead of appending it to a file.

I am running Ansible 2.8 and have figured out that it uses `urllib` to make the HTTP requests. But I cannot find any information on where it looks for CA certs on different operating systems.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer for Centos (other distros use different paths/binaries and I have no clue how this is managed on macintosh).

- Add your CA certificate file with a `.pem` extension to the `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` folder
- Run as root the command `update-ca-certificates`

The cert should now be recognized by ansible (and all other environments/softwares using openssl like e.g. curl)

If you still get validation errors, you can check what is the default path used by openssl

```
 openssl version -a | grep -i openssldir
```

In this directory, there should be a symbolic link `cert.pem` pointing to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem` (i.e. the CA Bundle file updated by `update-ca-certificates`). If this is missing, try to create it.

Comment: Yes, I haven't gotten around to CentOS yet since I got stuck on macOS but this would be my first attempt since that's the standard way to add custom CA on CentOS. But thanks for confirming that this works for Ansible. Now I just need to figure out the way to do this on macOS...

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are not less than 3 environment variables that you need to set with path to custom CA. Look at https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/pull/1439 for their exact names. Also be sure they are set on the machine that runs the http requests!!